# What brackets in array input mean

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

Why in some declarations of dynamic arrays we need to put array name in brackets:

```
(*allocMat)[count++] = row;
```

Comment: What is `allocMat`?

Comment: What exactly is `allocMat`  ?

Comment: My *guess* is that `allocMat` is a pointer to a pointer, emulating *pass by reference*. Then the parentheses are needed due to [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say more. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

It's about operator precedence, i.e. which part of the statement is executed first.

Like in simple math. Is `x = a + b*c` executed like `x = (a + b)*c` or like `x = a + (b*c)`?

So for your code the question is: Is `*` "stronger" than `[]` or is it the opposite?

Consider just doing:

```
*allocMat[count++] = row;
```

How would you expect that to be executed?

Like A:

```
(*allocMat)[count++] = row;
```

or like B:

```
*(allocMat[count++]) = row;
```

The answer is that it's executed like B so if you really want A then you need to explicit add the parenthesis.

An example where you would want A is when `allocMat` is a pointer to an array.

An example where you would want B is when `allocMat` is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The array subscript operator `[]` has higher priority than the unary dereference operator `*`. So, unless the parenthesis is used, a statement like

```
*allocMat[count++] = row;
```

will be parsed as

```
* (allocMat[count++]) = row;
```

which is not desired.

To properly evaluate the statement, we need to first dereference the pointer, and then, index onto it, like

```
(*allocMat)[count++] = row;
```

In the above snippet, `allocMat` is a pointer to an array. So, unless, the dereference is forced on higher priority, the subscripting operator `[]`, which has higher priority, will be taken into account first and will result in incorrect evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Allocmat is presumably a pointer to an array.

The parentheses are needed to get the indirection correctly. So `(*allocMat)[count++]` is the same as `allocMat[0][count++]`. Would you omit the parentheses, `*allocMat[count++]` would be equal to `allocMat[count++][0]` which is completely different. This is because operator precedence - `[]` binds slightly tighter than `*`.